# iOS UIViewControler singleton and how to use helper class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, singleton

I follow the online way to write singleton, each into SecondViewController, address of the print is the same , but why UISwitch interface is initialized ? I was into the original UIViewController? someone was also suggested to write helper class. Everthing is beginning, it is not very clear, Is there any Demo or explain the basic principles?How to write the code depend on second image?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFsVI.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ygtJ.png)

Comment: Why are you using a singleton view controller?

Comment: Try to add your code instead of image next time :)

Comment: I use switch to connect server(when switch is on),when I back to rootview,and go to secondview again,the switch is off.so I want to use singleton view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
static SecondViewController *sharedVCInstance = nil;
+ (SecondViewController *)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken = 0;

    dispatch_once (&onceToken, ^{
        if(sharedVCInstance == nil)
            sharedVCInstance = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedVCInstance;
}
```

Comment: I used this code,but I can turn to SecondViewController only once,I can not turn to SecondViewController again if I back to RootViewController.

Comment: What do you mean by turning to another view controller?

Comment: My SecondView has an UISwitchButton Connect Server when it's on.And I can receive message.Now I back to RootView and use Segue push to SecondView,the UISwitchButton is off,and the message is empty,and can't  receive message.

Comment: @MichaelZhan Can u add a dealloc method in your viewcontroller to check if the viewController is being deallocated

Comment: Could u look the second image,how to write this app?when I open the switchbutton,connect to server,and receive messages.but if I back to rootview,it isn't disconnect,but when I go to secondview again,the switchbutton is off,and can't show the messages.

Comment: Try adding a global variable in view controller 1 which keeps track whether you have connected to server or not. When you connect to server change the value of the variable. And when you comes back to 1st view controller and then to 2nd view controller, set the status of switch based on this variable value